# Given a range and a percentage - what is the best way to find the lowest number in that percentage?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Using a formula - I am trying to find the best way to input a range, a percent and find the lowest possible number that meets the criteria of that given percent.

For example - if given a range of random numbers between 1 and 20, and the percentage of 90% the formula would return 18 because the top 10% of that range can be 18 or higher.

Appreciate the help!

Answer (score 0):

> if given a range of random numbers between 1 and 20

```
=INDEX(RANDBETWEEN(1, SEQUENCE(20)))
```

[image]

---

> and the percentage of 90%

[image]

---

> the formula would return 18 because the top 10% of that range can be 18 or higher

so from this picture, the result would be `4, 10, 14, 15, 1, 2, 3, 7, 9`

[image]

---

therefore:

```
=INDEX(QUERY(QUERY(RANDBETWEEN(1, SEQUENCE(20)), 
 "select Col1,count(Col1)/20 
  group by Col1 
  label count(Col1)/20''"), 
 "where Col2 <= "&1-90%),,1)
```

[image]

Comment: Is the formula in A1 filling to A6 in your picture there? If so - it should only be showing 18 as 18 is the lowest threshold for 90% given random numbers 1 - 20. Also - is it possible to give the formula a range instead of using a single number (in your example you have 20 in the formula several times)?